# how to make angularjs partials a complete html files

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to make the AngularJS partial views a complete HTML files, so they will be easier to edit
and have Angular strip them to their body content (much like what the RequireJS text plugin does with the strip option)

I will clarify my question since the answer and comments show that it was not clear enough:

currently the content of the partial file is:

```
<p>{{value}}</p>
```

i want it to be:

```
<!doctype html>
<html><head><!-- with all things in the head to make it work stand alone HTML of Angular app --></head>
<body>
    <p>{{value}}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

So that i will be able to work on the partial as a stand alone app

Comment: You can use "templateUrl:" instead of "template:" ;)

Comment: Why is partial easier to edit when it contains the full HTML envelope?

Comment: Since then i can run it on itw own - find and correct its bugs without the rest of the app hanging down my neck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far the only answer i did found for this, is to actually use Angular with require.js - then I can leverage the text plugin and have my partials real apps.

The way to do it is to configure your app to load all templates using the text plugin of require with the strip option, then your views can have html with head and body that are ignored - so you can provide the necessary require.js files (it can share the same require.js configuration as the normal app if it is located at the same level as the normal app - i decided to place them in adjacent folders. but they do need different require.js main - so the main needs to reference the configuration)

Setting this up takes some effort, but it helps me develop large views with a lot of logic in them separately, and then just link them into my app as a view (while maintain the ability to access them separately, mostly for debugging)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the `ng-view` in your template `HTML` file, something like:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
     ...
    <head>
    <body ng-view>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then in your `$routeProvider` you can use `templateURL:`, like:

```
$routeProvider.when('/register', {templateUrl: 'partials/register.html', controller: 'RegisterCtrl'});
```

The file `partials/register.html` is a complete `HTML` file.